# What is the error with this tampermonkey code?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, tampermonkey, clearinterval

My goal is to go http://quizlet.com/12039115/scatter and get a score under 2 seconds. My plan is to do this by disabling the timer with setInterval/clearInterval.
I took some code off some site and tried adapting it to my purposes; it failed. Now I need to know what went wrong.
The original code can be found at [blog.jazzychad.net/2011/03/20/inspect-javascript-timers-greasemonkey.html](http://blog.jazzychad.net/2011/03/20/inspect-javascript-timers-greasemonkey.html). When I loaded this to Tampermonkey and ran it on the page, only setInterval printed out(multiple times):

```
INSPECT_TIMERS: setInterval - 100ms
quizlib.2X5g7.js:340
INSPECT_TIMERS: function (){return c.apply(b,a||arguments)}
```

Thus, I can see that it finds the timer id. Now i need to clearInterval(). Here's where stuff goes wrong.

Code that gave output above:

```
var go = function(window){

    var oldSetInterval = window.setInterval;
    var newSetInterval = function(f,t) {
        __log("INSPECT_TIMERS: setInterval - " + t + "ms");
        __log("INSPECT_TIMERS: " + f);
        var id = oldSetInterval(f,t);
        return id;
    };
    window.setInterval = newSetInterval;
    //setTimeoutDeleted
    function __log(msg) {
        if (window.console && window.console.log) {
            window.console.log(msg);
        }
    }
};

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
script.textContent = '(' + go + ')(window);';
document.body.appendChild(script); // run the script
```

When I add

```
clearInterval(id);
```

immediately before

```
return id;
```

the page literally fails to respond to the click to start the "game". Am I approaching this wrong? Do I need some sort of delay, or am I missing the big picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is, there are multiple `setInterval` calls, looks like 3 on my end.

If you run this code in your console before clicking "Start Game", it will log the following calls to `setInterval`.

```
var originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.setInterval = function(func, intr) {
    var id = originalSetInterval.apply(window, arguments);
    console.log('----setInterval----');
    console.log('function:', func);
    console.log('interval:', intr);
    console.log('id:', id);
    console.log('-------------------');
    return id;
};
```

Then when you click "Start Game", you will get output like the following.

```
----setInterval----
function: function()
interval: 17
id: 10
-------------------
----setInterval----
function: function()
interval: 17
id: 12
-------------------
----setInterval----
function: function()
interval: 100
id: 13
-------------------
```

**Feel free to stop reading here and do some experimenting on your own before continuing to read.**

You probably don't want to call `clearInterval` on all of these. The one that runs the clock appears to be the one with the `100` interval. To disable that interval without touching the other intervals, you can use a simple if statement.

```
var originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;
window.setInterval = function(func, intr) {
    var id = originalSetInterval.apply(window, arguments);
    console.log('----setInterval----');
    console.log('function:', func);
    console.log('interval:', intr);
    console.log('id:', id);
    console.log('-------------------');
    if (intr === 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
    }
    return id;
};
```

And doing this will successfully stop the clock. However, once you finish the game you will find that the game will still know how long you took. The clock is just a visual element.

If you want to cheat the game, you will need to target the code that actually calculates your final score. Sounds like a great opportunity to learn how to use your browser's developer tools, especially the JavaScript debugger (use the pretty-print feature to make the minified JS easier to read).

Comment: Wait. So none of this actually changes server-side. Wow ok. So can you point me to some resources to learn that javascript debugger stuff?

Comment: @JoeBob Mozilla has [some good tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger) for Firefox. Google also has [some tutorials](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) for Chrome.

Comment: Theres also promise with a cookie, as the admin himself alluded to: "key: scatter-{ID OF QUIZ}
value: number of tenths of seconds for your record time.
domain: quizlet.com" -- will this work?

Comment: And how can I use the javascript debugger to help my situation>

Comment: A slightly n00b question, but how will altering any of the code client-side produce changes server side?

Comment: @JoeBob I don't know, it's possible that such a technique will only appear locally to you. For debugging, pretty-print the code, and start looking for the code that decides your final time. Most-likely data functions are involved. Use breakpoints to inspect the code flow.

Comment: Presumably the game will create a request to the server, to record your score. Change the variable before that happens, and it will send your modified variable.

Comment: also, would i have to search through all the sources, or is there a specific file that usually has this info?

Comment: In prettyprint, I look for settimeout in the scatter default file;     `setTimeout(function() {
        var b = c.length, a = "";
        for (label in g)
            a += ", " + label;
        for (; b--; )
            f(c[b].labels.toString() + " UNFIRED; " + a.substr(2) + " DONE", "", "", "unfired_label")
    }, 2E4);
    var h = function() {
        QWait("quizlib", function() {
            QLoad("dom");
            QLoad("onload")
        })
    };`                    how will i use this?

Comment: that code looks pretty bad in comments but i dont have enough reputation to chat; is there another way i can talk to u?

Comment: I can't get the cookie to do anything, but I also don't know what the cookie is actually used for. There's only one JS file for the game, `scatter.K5JWz.js` on my end. Search for likely keywords. `gameOver` looks interesting. I don't have time to chat. Just keep at it, experiment, and learn!

Comment: @JoeBob You can't unless you setup a local proxy to replace the request response. You shouldn't need to do that to debug it though.

Comment: Ok, so I can set breakpoints and see the gameOver method, how do I debug it then? How can I use this debug tool to simulate the variable change I want?